# How can I re-create this customized Action Sheet with text field?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to figure out how I can re-create what I believe to be a customized Action Sheet (see photo link below) with a text field and two buttons. I'm relatively new to Swift, so I don't know whether an Action Sheet can be customized to this degree.

It would be helpful if someone could point me to any resources that could help me re-create this. Or if you believe this was created using a framework/library, which specific Cocoapod would be useful for my project. (Note: I am not using SwiftUI, so please exclude that in your recommendations.) Thanks.

[image: Custom Action Sheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. You can literally "re-create" that UI in your storyboard or do it in code. No need for fancy libraries that might get you stuck.

It does not matter if you're new to Swift or not. What you need to have a good grasp of is `UIKit`.

Here's the only material you need to learn, in my opinion. **Autolayout**

https://www.raywenderlich.com/811496-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-getting-started

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Glenn! Very helpful. Looks like I was just overthinking the solution here.

Comment: Wow, just have to add here that creating this in Storyboard and trying to use autolayout (so that it displays properly across all iPhone models) is a NIGHTMARE. Why does this have to be so difficult??? A real time-waster.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it might be a pain in the arse if you do it in the Storyboard. You can consider doing it in code alone, it's just a matter of personal preferences. Have a good grasp of constraints/autolayout and you'll be good.